# Switch focus between monitors in multi-monitor setup

Tags: windows, macos, keyboard-shortcuts, multiple-monitors, virtual-machine

I'm using a multi-monitor setup and I often use the second screen as a display for a virtual machine.
My problem is that I haven't found a good way to switch between the virtual machine and the host OS using only the keyboard.
Naturally, when the VM is focused, it will intercept <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>Tab</kbd> to switch between its own apps. Same goes for other shortcuts like <kbd>Win</kbd>+<kbd>1</kbd>, etc.

Can you suggest a utility (or a built-in mechanism) that can provide such a "switch to the foreground application on the other display" shortcut?

The host OS can be either Windows or Mac OS X.

Comment: Can you please specify which virtualization solution you are using? It highly depends on this.

Comment: I'm using VirutalBox on Windows and Parallels on the Mac

Comment: This sounds solvable using AutoHotKey. I will ask on their forum for a more timely reply.